# Use a Collection inside my custom collection?

Tags: java, oop

Is it correct to use an already implemented Collection (like a ArrayList) to implement my custom collection? Or could be there any problem?

Something like this:

```
public class customCollection<E> implements Collection <E> {
    List<E> objects = new ArrayList<E>();
}
```

Comment: There's no problem in principle; but implementing Collection directly (rather than List or Set, for example) is a bit unusual. What do you need your collection to do that's not already covered by an existing collection?

Comment: Also, consider extending [AbstractCollection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html) (or AbstractList or AbstractSet) instead.

Comment: Do you consider **not** following [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) a problem? I think the name of the class should be `CustomCollection`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Oh, I just didn't know about that abstract collections, I'm quite new on Java. I think I will better extend an Abstract...

Comment: @Abra Yes, that's true, just forgot about that when I asked this.

Answer (score 2):

That is absolutely OK. 
I have specialised data classes (that also have some business logic) that implement one standard type and have internally various objects for other reasons.

Take care to not produce unmaintainable code. For this, you could use tools such as SonarQube. Check, when you rely on (many) classes, how much do you use - in other words, how dependent is your class froom other interfaces, classes, inherited methods? See, for example http://tutorials.jenkov.com/ood/understanding-dependencies.html

Comment: "Take care not to produce unmaintainable code" is generally true, no? :) Perhaps you could expand on the specific concerns you have here.

Comment: Thank you! I also thought that it would probably be ok, but I was wondering if there could have any problem doing that.

Currently, it's just an academic work and I'm still learning, but I'll watch that SonarQube tool and also that page, I didn't even have thought about the dependencies.